# Asset Pipeline only creates application.css, but not for any of the required stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet, assets

So here's what the `application.css.scss` file looks like:

```
// require_tree .

body { color: red; }
```

And there are 3 other css files in the `app/assets/stylesheets/` directory.

The output? A single stylesheet tag in head, pointing at an uncompressed `application.css`.

Oddly enough the JavaScript is doing just fine, requiring all it needs.

I've checked this repository vs other repositories: No difference as far as I can tell in config variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're missing an `=`. Try this:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
*/

body {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the functions of the asset pipeline is the lump all the css into one file. Is there some styles which are not working as a result of the compilation?

Comment: The 'in one file' only happens on compression. This is in development mode.